# Searcher roto - JS - Handlebards - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

Estuve modificando algunas cosas de mi card y ahora el searcher se rompio. No logro encontrar donde esta el problema. Probe capturar diferentes padres pero no funciona.

```
<div class="row all-cards">
        
        <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="allCards">
            {{#each this}}
            <div class="col col-md-6 col-lg-3 limit show">
                <div class="card {{{3.v}}} shadow mb-5 mt-3 mx-auto show" >
                    <a class="text-decoration-none lopo" href="/country-detail.html?id={{{10.f}}}">
                    <img class="flag" src={{{9.v}}}
                        class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body mt-2 pb-5">
                        <h5 class="card-title mb-4">{{{0.v}}}</h5>
                        <h6>Population: {{{2.f}}}</h6>
                        <h6>Region: {{{4.v}}}</h6>
                        <h6>Capital: {{{5.v}}}</h6>
                        <h6 class="exact d-none">{{{3.v}}}</h6>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
        </div>
           {{/each}}
         </script>   
                
 
    </div>
```

aca les dejo la funcion obviamente

```
function searcher() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase()
      console.log(value)
      console.log($(".all-cards > div"))
      $(".all-cards > div").filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        $("#not-found").hide()
        var noResult = true
        $(".all-cards")
          .children("div")
          .each(function () {
            if ($(this).children(":visible").length != 0) {
              noResult = false
            }
          })
        if (noResult) {
          $("#not-found").show()
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Es raro por que esta funcion antes funcionaba perfecto. Recuerdo mover el a class lopo mas arriba  por eso probe capturar otras clases en la funcion pero sin exito.